# Task WaitAny condition

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I found some code that uses the Task.WaitAny condition.

```
Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[3];

tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); return 1; });
tasks[1] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return 2; });
tasks[2] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); return 3; });

while (tasks.Length > 0) {
    int i = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
    Task<int> completedTask = tasks[i];

    Console.WriteLine(completedTask.Result);

    var temp = tasks.ToList();
    temp.RemoveAt(i);
    tasks = temp.ToArray();
}
```

The code works fine, the result is 2 1 3.

When I tried to change the sleeping intervals

```
tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); return 1; });
tasks[1] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return 2; });
tasks[2] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return 3; });

while (tasks.Length > 0) {
    int i = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
    Task<int> completedTask = tasks[i];

    Console.WriteLine(completedTask.Result);

    var temp = tasks.ToList();
    temp.RemoveAt(i);
    tasks = temp.ToArray();
}
```

I got 1 2 3, despite task number two is the one with the smallest sleeping time and should be the one removed first.

What is happening under the hood?

Comment: Maybe some timing issue. Increase the sleep intervals by 10x to rule that out.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - I get "(pause) 2,3 (pause) 1" or "(pause) 3,2 (pause) 1"- as expected. How many cores do you have on your PC? Is is possible that it is taking time to spin up workers because you have a single-core?

Comment: btw, is the 1000, 1000 a typo? should one of those be 3000?

Comment: I am on an i7 running Windows 7 on WmWare 5. increasing the intervals by a tenfold solved it. What do you mean with a timing issue?

Comment: @user1648371 you can never rely that sleep (or other waits) wake up the thread after a given period. This is always the *minimum* wait period. Why it doesn't work in your case is unknown to me, though. Marc has found a possible explanation.

Comment: @user1648371 Does that mean that you're running this code on a virtual single-core machine? If that's the case, I think Marc is right: `ThreadPool` quickly creates as many threads as you have cores, but additional threads are created slowly.

Comment: I checked VMWare options and Windows was running only with one processor. Increasing that number fixed it. Make an answer out of it and I'll accept it.

Comment: Nice catch, @MarcGravell :)

Comment: Well when I run your second example it runs exactly as you want to - 2 3 1. I don't know why you have this issue on your machine but the code is running fine

Answer (score 1):

Thread.Sleep is fairly accurate in pausing the program for the specified number of milliseconds.

Thread.Sleep(1000) means that task will be available for execution after 1000 millisecond.

But which task is to be execute first from all the available tasks is decided by task scheduler,it decide the order of execution of task based on number of threads in thread-pool and many other factors.